# I attached an onClick prompt to an SVG image, but i cant get the prompt to run a jQuery if else statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg

I'm making an SVG map of the US most of it is done so far, its all down to a simple if else statement so that i can finish. The goal is if i click on a state (i have the path and id for every state) a prompt will pop up asking for state name. The jQuery code is then supposed to fill the state green if answer i put into the prompt is correct, and red if incorrect. It does fill red when i enter something into the prompt, however it does this every time, even when the prompt is correct. How can i fix this please i need a quick answer by today. 
Here is the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/vnqcyu90/

```
 jQuery(function($) {
$('path').click(function() {
  prompt("Enter State Initials")
  if ($('path id') == prompt) {
    this.style.fill = "green";
  } else {
    this.style.fill = "red";
  }



});
```

});

that's the specific line of code causing me issues, it both adds the onclick function to the SVG map, as well as handle the if else statement related to the prompt asking the name of the state which in my case is the path id. (This code is jQuery 1.7.1)

Comment: Hi Wes, welcome to Stack Overflow. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. See: How to create a [mcve]

Comment: How can we answer this without seeing your code? Please create a [mcve] and paste it into the question.

Comment: trying to figure out best way to post code now one second sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems with your code.

First, you are not assigning the result of `Window.prompt()` to anything.  You need to do:

```
var prompt = window.prompt("Enter State Initials");
```

The next problem is your jQuery selector

```
$('path id')
```

jQuery selectors return a list of elements that match your selector string.  In this case, you are asking it to return all elements named "id" (ie. `<id>`) who have an ancestor `<path>` element.

If you want to check the id value of the path you click on, then what you need to do is:

```
$(this).get(0).id
```

`$(this)` turns the clicked element into a jQuery object. The `get(0)` gets the first element of the jQuery object (remember jQuery selectors always return a list). In this case however, there will only ever be one element in the list.

And you get read the id attribute of the element simply by referencing the `id` property of the element.

So your final code would look like:

```
var prompt = window.prompt("Enter State Initials")
if ($(this).get(0).id == prompt) {
  this.style.fill = "green";
} else {
  this.style.fill = "red";
}
```

Since all your state ids are uppercase, you'll probably also want to convert the text people type in.  For example:

```
var prompt = window.prompt("Enter State Initials").toUpperCase();
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vnqcyu90/1/)

Comment: thanks so much it works exactly like i wanted it to.